How to derive Diffusion Model's reverse conditional probability when it's tractable via conditioning on $x_0$

Can anyone help me with understanding how the $\tilde{\beta}$ and ${\tilde\mu_t{(x_t, x_0)}}$ are derived?
It seems to me that exponential term is a 2nd order polynomial term and it doesn't really look like a gaussian in the form of $\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$.
Source:https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/#reverse-diffusion-process

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems you've already understood up to the step of the exact conditional probability of the reverse diffusion process $q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}|\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)$ which is proportional to the exponential of your mentioned 2nd order polynomial with 3 terms per Bayes theorem along with conditional probabilities defined in the forward diffusion process with some mentioned nice property.
Since the Gaussian distribution is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\tilde{\beta}}}\text{exp}(-\frac{(x-\tilde{\mu})^2}{2\tilde{\beta}})$ (consistent with your reference where we use $\tilde{\beta}$ as the variance parameter), apparently to match the above proportional functional form with the Gaussian, one has to match the corresponding coefficients of the 3 terms of the 2nd order polynomial inside $\text{exp}$. Thus you clearly have $-\frac{1}{2\tilde{\beta}}=-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\alpha_t}{\beta_t}+\frac{1}{1-\bar{\alpha_{t-1}}})$ from matching the leading term. This is nothing but the next line in your reference where you see $\tilde{\beta}_t=1/(\frac{\alpha_t}{\beta_t}+\frac{1}{1-\bar{\alpha_{t-1}}})$.
Similarly from matching the second term you have the functional form of $\tilde{\mu}$ which can also be expressed as $\tilde{\mu_t}(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)$, which can be also expressed as $\tilde{\mu_t}(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{\epsilon}_t)$ with the mentioned nice property in the forward diffusion process. Note there's no utility from matching the third constant term here.
